# Does \r stand for something in sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, mathjax, docstring, numpydoc

I'm writing my docstring following the numpy docstring guidelines. Then I use sphinx's autodoc to generate my documentation. Within some docstrings I'm using LaTeX formulas (sphinx.ext.mathjax). It seems that `\r` means something special like a new line. If I have the following command:

```
"""
This :math:`\langle a, b\rangle` denotes the dot product of a and b
"""
```

it doesn't properly render. It puts like angle to a new line and gives me an error: *Inline interpreted text or phrase reference start-string without end-string*
If I replace the \rangle with \langle everything works fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: \r is legal SphinxQL space now http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/view.php?id=332

Comment: Not just in Sphinx - `\r` is the carriage return character in a lot of places.

Comment: @planet260 thx for the comment. But how can I then make this work:)

Comment: Escape with a double slash or place a "r" (without the quotes) in from of the triple quotes, this disables the interpretation of the slashes inside the quotes: `r"""" text \langle """`

Comment: @planet260: The question is about the Sphinx documentation tool, which is unrelated to the Sphinx search engine.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl thanks alot! that works like a charm! If you want to add is an answer I will accept it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to escape with a double slash or place a "r" (without the quotes) in from of the triple quotes, this disables the interpretation of the slashes inside the quotes:

```
r"""
This :math:`\langle a, b\rangle` denotes the dot product of a and b
"""
```

There are several prefixes that influence the definition of string literals, see the [documentation of Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Relevant excerpts:

> The backslash () character is used to escape characters that
>   otherwise have a special meaning, such as newline, backslash itself,
>   or the quote character.

and

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a
>   letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat
>   backslashes as literal characters. As a result, in string literals,
>   '\U' and '\u' escapes in raw strings are not treated specially.